# Вызов виртуального метода в конструкторе

Tags: c++

Помогите разобраться с наследованием и виртуальными функциями. Есть такой класс:
.h -

```
#ifndef CUSTOMSUBWINDOW_H
#define CUSTOMSUBWINDOW_H

#include <QMdiSubWindow>

class CustomSubWindow : public QMdiSubWindow
{
public:
    explicit CustomSubWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual void createUI();
};

#endif // CUSTOMSUBWINDOW_H
```

.cpp -

```
#include "CustomSubWindow.h"

CustomSubWindow::CustomSubWindow(QWidget *parent) :QMdiSubWindow(parent)
{
    createUI();
}
void CustomSubWindow::createUI()
{
}
```

Есть класс-наследник:
.h -

```
#ifndef CAT_PRODUCTS_H
#define CAT_PRODUCTS_H

#include <CustomSubWindow.h>

class CatProducts : public CustomSubWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CatProducts(QWidget *parent = 0);
    void createUI();
};

#endif // CAT_PRODUCTS_H
```

.срр-

```
#include "CatProducts.h"

CatProducts::CatProducts(QWidget *parent) : CustomSubWindow(parent)
{
}

void CatProducts::createUI()
{
    setWindowTitle("Справочник товаров!!!");
}
```

Т.е. в наследнике мы переопределяем метод `createUI()`, который вызывается в конструкторе базового класса. Как я понимаю, нужно использовать позднее связывание, т.е. объявить метод виртуальным. Но это не работает. В чём я не прав?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Когда создается объект производного класса, сначала вызывается конструктор базового класса.
В этот момент еще НЕТ объекта производного класса, поэтому вызов виртуальной функции и позднее связывание невозможны - вызываются только функции создаваемого класса.

В конструкторе виртуальность не работает *и не может* работать: подумайте сами, как конструктор **базового** класса может знать - вызван ли он для создания объекта **базового** класса или объекта какого-то из **производных** классов (которых в момент написания базового класса не было и в проекте...)?

Comment: Благодарю. Почему об этом не пишут в учебниках?

Comment: Насчёт того, что виртуальность _не может_ работать, не вполне так. В C#, например, виртуальные вызовы в конструкторе работают, т. к. таблица виртуальных методов строится в начале конструктора, перед вызовом базового. Так что такое поведение C++ не необходимость, а произвольное решение авторов языка.

Comment: @Artik,, пишут. «The C++ Programming Language 4th ed.» 20.3.2 и 22.4

Comment: @VladD, что делает вызовы в C# опасными, в отличии от C++, в котором они только с-толку-сбивающие.

Comment: @ixSci: В C++ вызов виртуальной функции, особенно косвенный, **молча**, без предупреждения, приводит к неожиданным результатам. Я бы не назвал такое поведение безопасным.

Comment: @VladD, это всегда нормальный вызов функции класса и не может привести к обращению к неинициализированным членам(исключаем глобальные переменные), поэтому, в общем случае, вызов безопасен. Хотя и не очевиден. Не пытаюсь доказать, что решение в C++ лучше, просто безопаснее. На мой взгляд, в обоих языках, лучше было вообще запретить эту возможность, либо же сделать более явной.

Comment: "В конструкторе виртуальность не работает и не может работать...". В конструкторе виртуальность *работает* и работает так же как и всегда: выбор конкретной функции для вызова делается на основе *динамического* типа объекта. Только не надо забывать, что во время работы конструктора класса `A` динамический тип конструируемого объекта - именно `A`. Поэтому виртуальность в иерархии работает от корня иерархии и вниз вплоть до типа `A`, но не ниже. Пока мы не "упираемся" в тип A, виртуальность работает "привычным" образом.

Comment: @ixSci: Ну, эта часть понятна, но я всё равно не назвал бы это поведение безопасным. Если программист считает, что функция вызывается, а реально она _не_ вызывается _в некоторых случаях_ (а увидеть проблему при косвенном вызове шансов никаких), то это дорога к проблемам.

Comment: @Harry Хорошо, а если стоит, к примеру,  такая задача: при создании экземпляра потомка некая информация (например metaObject()->className() этого потомка) должна передаваться в метод, реализованный в предке. А этот метод должен вызываться при создании потомка. Тут только передавать эту информацию в качестве параметра метода и вызывать его явно в конструкторе потомка? Автоматизировать это способа нет?

Comment: @Artik Да, я бы поступал именно так - либо передачей через параметр конструктора базового, либо установкой в конструкторе потомка.

Comment: @VladD Можно - если захотеть - и в C++ - например, с передачей в конструктор указателя на член класса. Только такая конструкция говорит скорее о непродуманности дизайна. Imho, конечно...

Comment: @AnT Это скорее не виртуальность, потому что, как я понимаю, позднее связывание тут не работает. Вызовы разрешаются при компиляции, а не через vtable.

Comment: @Harry: Мне кажется, что всё же через vtable. Посмотрите пример в моём ответе.

Comment: @VladD Вот во что разворачивает ваш код VC++: http://vpaste.net/WoGLY Получается, что вызов Second::Report разрешается во время компиляции?

Comment: @Harry: Ну, это оптимизатор всё заинлайнил. Положите First, Second и Third в разные DLL, чтобы оптимизатор не видел их, тогда ему без ТВМ не обойтись. Или просто посмотрите, во что компилируется `CallReport`. :)

Comment: @VladD Вот, еще - у вас все же ситуация несколько иная: в момент вызова Report уже есть First, так что vtable уже есть... Вобщем, по позднему времени я уже окончательно запутался, подумаю завтра.

Answer (score 8):

По определению, вызовы виртуальных методов в языке С++ связываются с конкретной реализацией метода на основе анализа *динамического* типа объекта, использованного в таком вызове. В этом их отличие от невиртуальных вызовов, которые связываются на основе *статического* типа объекта.

Так вот, в языке С++ во время непосредственной работы конструктора (или деструктора) класса `A` динамической тип конструируемого объекта принимается равным именно `A`. То есть даже если конструируемый объект типа `A` является базовым подобъектом какого-то объекта класса-наследника `B`, динамический тип конструируемого объекта во время работы конструктора `A` - это именно `A`. Только когда конструктор класса `A` закончит свою работу и передаст управление конструктору класса `B`, динамический тип конструируемого объекта магическим образом изменится и станет `B`.

Это означает, что все виртуальные механизмы во время активности конструктора класса `A` продолжают работать как обычно, но при этом их функциональность будет ограничена снизу классом `A`: виртуальные функции будут выбираться только из класса `A` и классов, расположенных выше по иерархии (классов-предков класса `A`), но не из классов, расположенных ниже по иерархии(не из классов-наследников).

Именно это вы и наблюдаете.

P.S. Утверждения о том, что виртуальные вызовы, сделанные из конструктора, якобы "не работают" или "ведут себя как невиртуальные", не соответствуют действительности. Виртуальные методы ведут себя как всегда - в полном соответствии с динамическим типом конструируемого объекта. Иллюзия "невиртуальности" возникает только из-за тривиальности и непоказательности рассматриваемого примера: совершающий виртуальный вызов класс вообще не имеет предков.

Comment: Сюда бы сносочку на Стандарт добавить для закрепления правоты так сказать.

Comment: Спасибо, доступно.

Comment: Иллюзия, не иллюзия, какая разница? Поведение неполиморфное и всё. Что, собственно, и заставило автора задать вопрос — функция ведёт себя не так, как пользователь ожидал. Поэтому оба ответа, что у Вас указаны как «не соответствующие действительности», оной соответствуют.

Answer (score 4):

В C++, виртуальные функции ведут себя как **не**виртуальные, когда вызываются из конструктора или деструктора.

Answer (score 3):

В поддержку финального замечания из ответа @AnT, небольшой воспроизводящий пример:

```
class First
{
public:
    virtual void Report() { cout << "First" << endl; }
    void CallReport() { Report(); }
};

class Second : public First
{
public:
    virtual void Report() { cout << "Second" << endl; }
    Second() { CallReport(); }
};

class Third : public Second
{
public:
    virtual void Report() { cout << "Third" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Third third;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/zOsWbO

Этот пример выводит `Second`. Функция `CallReport` производит вызов виртуального метода `Report`. В конструкторе `Second` типом объекта *является* `Second`, и виртуальный вызов разрешается в `Second::Report`.

Comment: Но если я правильно понимаю, тут нет позднего связывания...

Comment: @Mikhailo: Как же нету? А откуда методу `CallReport` на этапе компиляции знать, что ему нужно вызвать именно `Second::Report`?