# Запуск потока из абстрактного базового класса

Tags: c++, многопоточность, наследование, виртуальная-функция

Нужно что бы конструктор абстрактного базового класса запускал в отдельном потоке 
чисто виртуальный метод, определённый дочерним классом. Что-то похожее на

```
struct A {
    virtual void ex() = 0;
    A() {
        thread(ex); //Должен запуститься метод B::ex()
    }
};

struct B :A {
    void ex() {
        cout << "ex\n";
    }
};
```

Я пытался передавать в базовый конструктор указатель на метод, который нужно запустить, из дочернего конструктора:

```
struct A {
    virtual void ex() = 0;

    template<typename F, typename T>
    A(F f, T t) {
        thread tr(f, t);
    }
};

struct B :A {
    void ex() {
        cout << "ex\n";
    }
    B() :A(&B::ex, this) {}
};
```

Вылетает ошибка abort has been called.

Как можно добиться подобного поведения?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вызов виртуального метода в конструкторе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604553/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%80%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d1%83%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2):

Никак. Вызов виртуальных методов дочернего класса в конструкторе базового - UB

Comment: как и в деструкторе