Разница между неопределенным и неуточненным поведением
Суть вопроса: прочитал, что не стоит вызывать виртуальные методы в конструкторе базового класса, так как в момент конструирования таблица виртуальных функций может быть еще не заполнена. Говорит ли что то стандарт языка об этой ситуации? Зависит ли это от реализации?
Если обобщить вопрос: как в общем случае отличить undefined behaviour от unspecified?

Я бы дал ссылку на другой ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/604553/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5#comments-link-604586

@Chorkov добавил

Как заголовок связан с вопросом?
